# How to animate window output from 2D array of x and y screen co-ordinates

Tags: c++, win32gui

I have a set of 2D array(IntMatrix to be exact) that possess values in certain index (if value is 1, it will print to screen).
The following is how I populated the 2D array when i press a button.

```
case IDC_SOLVE_BUTTON:
        trysolve = 1;
        solve2D.resize(inRowCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < inRowCount; i++){
            solve2D[i].resize(inColCount);
        }
        solve2D[0][3] = 1;
        solve2D[1][3] = 1;
        solve2D[1][4] = 1;
        solve2D[1][5] = 1;
        solve2D[2][5] = 1;
```

Now that I have values in some of the array indices, I know how to print them onto my window as shown below :

```
for (int rowId = 0; rowId < inRowCount; rowId++){
    for (int colId = 0; colId < inColCount; colId++){
        check = (colId*inColCount) + (rowId);

            if (solve2D[rowId][colId] == 1){
            solvecheck = (colId*inColCount) + (rowId);
            startCol = colId * 10;
            startRow = rowId * 10;
            RECT cell = { startCol, startRow, startCol + dCol, startRow + dRow };
            FillRect(hdc, &cell, tBrush);
            }

        }
```

Now important question is how do i exactly animate the printing ? Such that it will print one RECTANGLE, then print the subsequent RECTANGLE one second later. Any way i can set a timer and update the window at the printing segment of the code ??

Appreiciate some guidiance in this. Please help !

Comment: Do what you said: Set a timer and update the window on the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Sleep function to make the program wait for 1 second before continuing. As follows:

```
Sleep(1000);
```

Notice that the parameter is in milli-seconds, so you need 1000 to represent one second.

Place this function call in the suitable place of your code and you'll be done.

Comment: Um, no. This will hang your program because you are sleeping instead of processing events.